# springboot oauth how to validate access_token

Tags: spring-boot, oauth

Hello everyone hope you doing well,

i have problem using open authentication in spring boot, when accessing page rest with postman is not even using param access token it still show the result, this my code please help???

Authorization Server Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;
@Autowired
private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) 
throws Exception {

  endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler);
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clients.inMemory()
    .withClient("admin").secret("123")
    .scopes("read","write")
    .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5*60)
    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(10*60);
}

}
```

Resource Server Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**") /** this
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityUtility hash;
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/", "/css/**", "/image/**", "/js/**", "/newUser",
            "/forgetPassword", "/login", "/logout", "/fonts/**", "/signUp", "/register", "/sendEmail", "/logout", "/tes","/oauth2/**","/api/**",
            "/admin/tes","/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example/**",
            "/admin/tes2" };
    private static final String[] ADMIN_MATCHERS = { "/admin", "/admin/**" };
    private static final String[] OAUTH2_PAGE = { "/oauth/**", "/api/**" };

    private final String USERS_QUERY = "select username, password, is_enabled from user where username=?";
    private final String ROLES_QUERY = "select u.username, u.is_enabled, r.name as authority from user u "
            + "inner join user_role ur on (u.id = ur.user_id) " + "inner join role r on (ur.role_id = r.roleid) "
            + "where username=?";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/app-login").usernameParameter("app_username")
                .passwordParameter("app_password").defaultSuccessUrl("/myAccount").permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(ADMIN_MATCHERS).hasRole("ADMIN");
//      http.csrf().disable();
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers(OAUTH2_PAGE);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // temporary
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("test");
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(hash.passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

Auth Controller

```
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthController {
    @GetMapping("/api/demo1")
    public String apiTes() {
        System.out.println("sysout mas");
        return "return result";
    }
}
```

[image: postman result without params]

Answer (score 0):

solved guys, it because i was using springboot 1.5.10 so i have to add

> security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3

to spring application.properties